# How can I upgrade pip on Ubuntu 10.04? 

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, pip

On Ubuntu 10.04 I've used `apt-get install pip` to install `pip` after which I installed `django`. Then I tried to uninstall `django` with `pip` via `pip uninstall django` which gives me:

```
pip: error: No command by the name pip uninstall
```

From doing some research that is because I'm using an older version.

```
$pip --version
pip 0.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)
```

I first realized that this version of `pip` did not have uninstall when I installed the wrong version of `django` and tried to uninstall it with

```
pip uninstall django
```

and ended up with

```
pip: error: No command by the name pip uninstall
```

From another article:

> pip 0.3.1 is over two years old, and indeed it does not include the
>   uninstall command. The current version of pip is 1.0.1.
>
> I presume you're using an OS-packaged version of pip; those tend to be
>   quite out of date. Quite a few bugs have been fixed and features added
>   in the last couple years.

So what is the correct way to upgrade it on Ubuntu 10.04 so that I can gain access to the `uninstall` command?

Comment: try using `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I tried that, it said that it upgraded but then using `pip --version` still gives the same version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove your system wide installation of pip:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

Then install a fresh copy of pip:

```
curl  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Tested on ubuntu 10.04 i686

I suggest you to use virtualenv. For further details see the [Official pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: I would use `easy_install pip` instead of the `curl` command.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to ask for [backporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) python-pip 1.0-1 from Ubuntu Oneiric to Lucid. Of course, you can do this manually by yourself, too.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, `pip install --upgrade pip` does work, but it install a *new* pip, in my case pip-2.6. So the command to uninstall is `pip-2.6 uninstall package-name`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case after a `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` on ubuntu 10.04
`/usr/bin/pip` is unchanged but `/usr/local/bin/pip` is pip 1.1

```
pip --version
pip 0.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)

/usr/local/bin/pip --version
pip 1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages (python 2.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Default install prefix is `/usr/local`, use:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --install-option="--prefix=/usr" pip
```

Comment: I was using pip 1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. The way I originally installed pip was by running `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. I wanted to upgrade, so I tried your solution. Afterwards, `which pip` did, in fact, output `/usr/bin/pip`, as expected, but running `pip --version` had an error ending with this: `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.5`

Answer (score 0):

My case: I first removed the old pip and then re-installed the latest version.

```
apt-get remove python-pip;
curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | sudo python;
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip;
```